# How would you justify to a non-statistician why we should use an unbiased estimator instead of a maximum likelihood estimator?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimators, unbiased-estimator, communication

Say we have the maximum likelihood estimator (which is usually biased) and an unbiased estimator and the sample size is small enough that these estimator are substantially different in magnitude. We're also dealing with stakeholders who have a strong interest in the outcome and are not themselves statisticians (I think a court of law may be a good example). Why should we choose the unbiased estimator over the maximum likelihood estimator? The unbiased estimator has the correct expected value, but why is having the right expected value better than being the single most likely possible value like the maximum likelihood estimator? How would I explain in a near-adversarial context why I should choose one over the other?

Comment: +1 but should we?

Comment: @Dave Fair question; if you can argue we should not use the unbiased estimator, go for it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Estimating_a_Poisson_probability gives an example where you really do not want an unbiased estimator, while https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem#One_tank gives an example where the maximum likelihood estimator does not look good.  So the question is really about what makes one estimator better than another

Comment: I would flip the question: why would we choose the ML estimator?  Its justification is primarily asymptotic and independent of whatever your actual loss function might be, so in this extremely general (and therefore vague) setting, ML estimators have little justification at all. If your loss is approximately quadratic, then "unbiased" means *minimum loss* (within some family of estimators), making that choice *directly* related to your loss.  Assuming this is the situation, that's why the burden of the argument falls on your adversary rather than you.

Comment: @whuber I think that's an excellent answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, please understand I am not advocating automatic use of *either* kind of estimator.  Unbiased estimators have plenty of problems, too.  They might not exist and they might give really bad estimates on average.  The choice of estimator needs to depend on our conception of the data (our statistical model) and on how our results will be used (the loss function or its equivalent).  As a general proposition you pose a false dichotomy: you needn't ever choose one of these two approaches over the other.  Plenty of other kinds of procedures are available for consideration.

Comment: To give an example where it might seem plausible that an unbiased estimator performs better than the MLE, consider a uniform distribution on $[0, \theta]$ with unknown $\theta$. The maximum likelihood estimation is the largest observation while the UMVUE considers the number of samples (as a factor $(n+1)/n$). For a very small sample size (say $n=1$), the MLE is going to be far off from the actual parameter. When you wait for a bus that comes ever $\theta$ minutes and you had to wait for $X$ minutes, having arrived randomly, the intuitive guess is not $\theta=X$, but $\theta>X$.

Comment: @whuber: I do not understand the claim that *ML estimators have little justification at all.* that szeems far too strong --- at least they have an intuitive justification, and does often work well, at least when there are few parameters ...

Comment: @Kjetil First, "intuitive justification" is off the table--that's no support at all.  "Does often work well" is an appeal to some vague body of experience and again is inadequate.  (I do not deny the value of both aspects of ML--I'm only pointing out the lack of rigor or logical justification in them.)  It is indisputable that ML makes no use whatsoever of a loss function.  So, whenever statistics is applied to make decisions or take actions, *ML has no inherent relevance to the problem!*  Far from being "too strong," my statement actually is a little toned down.

Comment: @whuber Wouldn't the negative log-likelihood be a loss function?

Comment: @Dave E. L. Lehmann, among others, requires that "the loss is zero when the correct value is estimated," in part because that permits defining a reasonable risk function.